# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FORM_KEY' -- Magento

Tags: php, magento

After upgrading from Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.0 I've run intop a error and can't find a solution anywhere.

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FORM_KEY' in \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Cart.php on line 67
```

No other errors in system.log, exception.log or php error.log. Just this error printout on the page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR unlikely to be the Magento cache, which is parsed XML configuration. The helper code would more likely be cached in the server or have a local override as fschmengler mentions below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class constant is `Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY` and did not exist yet in Magento 1.7

If you use the Magento compiler active (you shouldn't, see: [when should I use the Magento compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)), recompile. If you use an opcode cache like APC, flush it.

But most likely the issue is that you made a copy of this class in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php` to hack some changes into it. Check what you changed there, replace it with the new file from `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php` and re-apply your changes<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. Even better, don't put anything in `app/code/local/Mage` and user proper class rewriting</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I replaced the file to local/Mage...  but I didn't touch the core files! :) Thanks